# Facebook send dialog to multiple friends using a recipients arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook

The Facebook new Send Dialog lets people to send content to specific friends. But the API @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/ said the parameter 'TO' means "A user ID or username".

I wonder is there a method to send message to multiple friends at one time. I tried to set the 'to' as a javascript arrays, but that does not work.

Comment: It currently doesn't work and it's not planned. See [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197423096996631) for more details.

Comment: bug URL is now https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122529667888371

Answer (score 8):

It seems that currently the sdk only takes the first element from the array that is passed to "To" parameter. This is really annoying and no formal explanation is given to this design decision. I'd wish it can take more than one uids or emails, group names etc.

Comment: It's so that they aren't building a platform where developers can spam by default.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how you're doing it or what you define as "works", but the below kind of works:

Go to the javascript test console here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/
And type in the following, and hit run, it will bring up a send dialog with two names prepopulated. Unfortunately, when you hit send, it goes to an error page (still trying to figure that one out). But still, it does populate the dialog with two names :P

```
<script>
    FB.ui(
     { 
      method: 'send', 
      to: [5,6],
      link: "https://developers.facebook.com",
      picture: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174597_20531316728_2866555_q.jpg"
     }, 
     function(param){
            // If they cancel params will show: 
            //    {action:false, ...}
            // and if they send the friend request it'll have:
            //    {action:true, ...}
            // and if they closed the pop-up window then:
            //    param is undefined
     }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Note that this does not seem to work when using a straight url and not the javascript sdk. Filed as bug http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18806. We'll see if it gets any traction...

Comment: Filed the error when clicking send as http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18804

Comment: When I use this, it gives this error in the send DB:  `This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Should not use user's username (6)`. This arised when i gave to: field.

Answer (score 7):

Seems both ways, direct URL and Javascript don't allow to use a list of ID's , just checked and verified it today

Answer (score 2):

I tried with a comma separated list of IDs, in the 'TO' field, and it worked ;)

Comment: From what I can gather, this feature DID work as of October 2011 but doesn't work as of sometime before April 2012. Although Pinterest is somehow still doing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126399/duplicate-pinterest-facebook-invite-functionality