# Facebook 'send' dialog to multiple friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The idea is that the user can request feedback on what they have made from a couple of friends.

I have a friend selector which is working great.

From here I get the user id's. I then call the send dialog and instead there being multiple recipients there is only one. Does anyone know why?

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Test',
    to: formattedContacts,
    link: 'http://google.com'
});
```

If I log the formattedContacts I get the following. (id's removed)

```
["11111", "222222"]
```

The send dialog appears fine but only the first users appears as a recipent.

Does anyone know how to open the dialog with multiple recipients?

Answer (score 0):

Send dialog only provides way to chose one user automatically. User who see dialog may add other users as well, but application currently cannot do this.

From [Send Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/):

> `to` - A `user ID` or `username` to which to send the message. Once the dialog comes up, the **user can specify additional users, Facebook groups, and email addresses** to which to send the message. Sending content to a Facebook group will post it to the group's wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the FB js-sdk you can specify multiple recipients like so:

```
FB.ui({
      method : 'send',
      to : [12345, 99999, 54321],
      link : "http://google.com/"
    }, function(param) {
      console.log(param);
});
```

But yes, popping the Send Dialog using a url (instead of using FB.ui()) will accept one UID only.