# Send message to multiple recipients using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, dialog, send

Is there any other way to post message to multiple recipients.
We've tried to integrate logic, described here [Facebook send dialog to multiple friends using a recipients arrays](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6469748/facebook-send-dialog-to-multiple-friends-using-a-recipients-arrays)
but it doesn't look it works now. It just allows to send information to first recipient in the list of IDs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See this answer, the solution seems to use an array with Facebook user IDs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469748/facebook-send-dialog-to-multiple-friends-using-a-recipients-arrays

Answer (score 5):

I’ve found a workaround for sending Facebook messages to multiple friends.
Every Facebook user automatically got an @facebook.com e-mail address.
The address is the same as the public username or public user ID.
So you can simply send an regular e-mail to this e-mail addresses.
The mail will be displayed in the Facebook inbox like a normal message.
It’s important that you use the connected users email as sender, otherwise it won’t work.
Here's an example that gets all friends e-mail adresses and calls a web service.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '#APP_ID#',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            GetData();
        } else {
            Login();
        }
    });

    function Login() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                GetData();
            }
        }, { scope: 'email' });
    }

    function GetData() {
        //Get user data
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            //Sender
            var sender = response.email;

            //Get friends
            FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {

                //Recepients array
                var recipients = [];
                var length = response.data.length;
                var counter = 0;

                //Loop through friends
                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var id = response.data[i].id;

                    //Get friend data
                    FB.api('/' + id, function (response) {
                        var recipient = "";

                        //User got a username, take username
                        if (response.username) {
                            recipient = response.username + '@facebook.com';
                        }
                        //No username, take id
                        else {
                            recipient = response.id + '@facebook.com';
                        }

                        //Add e-mail address to array
                        recipients.push(recipient);

                        counter++;
                        //last email -> send
                        if (counter == length) {
                            SendEmail(sender, recipients);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function SendEmail(sender, recipients) {
        //Call webservice to send e-mail e.g.
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '#WEBSERVICE#',
            data: '{ sender:"' + sender + '", recipients: ["' + recipients.join('","') + '"] }',
            success: function (response) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to send messages to @facebook.com addresses, but they're always being hidden in the "spam" folder. Any ideas? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44844/why-does-email-sent-to-my-facebook-com-address-always-end-up-in-facebook-messag

Comment: Worth noting that this feature doesn't work anymore and email sent to user_id@facebook.com will bounce.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't want you to do this, so you'll have to do a work-around... You can develop an app with a built-in messaging system. Then send a **request** to multiple recipients at the same time. When the users click on the request, your app should retrieve and display the message.