# Duplicate Pinterest Facebook invite functionality

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to duplicate Pinterest's "Invite Friends" functionality. In case you haven't seen what it looks like, it looks like this:
[image]

This important points here are 1) there are multiple recipients and 2) you can type a custom message.

So far, with the Facebook API, I've only found ways to send a custom message to a single user or send a pre-canned message to multiple users. I haven't found a way to send a custom message to multiple users.

Here's what will let you send a custom message to just one user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

And here's what will let you send a pre-canned message to multiple users:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

So how are they doing it? How can I allow my user to send a custom message to multiple recipients like Pinterest is doing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Facebook responded to a bug report about this about a week ago, stating it was "by design". Pinterest, among other apps, are whitelisted to be able to include multiple recipients. How to get whitelisted? Beyond me.

See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/314701778595814 for full official response from Facebook (and frustrated responses by developers).

Comment: This is correct - it was always documented as one prefilled recipient and apart from a bug on our side which opened this up to everyone, only whitelisted partners are able to prefill multiple recipients

Comment: How can you become a "whitelisted partner"?

Comment: There isn't really a process to apply, if you have an account manager or a contact in the partnerships department you can ask them for more information, but there isn't a general application process

Comment: Getting whitelisted? Spend $100,000+ a month on FB advertising :D

Comment: Pinterest now sends them one at a time. They show a page with invite next to each friend and each button brings up the dialog.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore? I wonder what's happened with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an array to FB.ui as the `to` param. That'll let you choose recipients. Or, populate the array with some UIDs, to prepopulate the recipients.

```
FB.ui({
  method: "send",
  to:[],
  name: "Join my site, now!",
  description: "...",
  picture: "...",
  link: 'http://...'
})
```

Comment: The problem is that if I specify multiple UIDs for `to`, it will only prepopulate the "To:" field with the first one.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing as Leventix, and I don't want to make the user have to choose recipients.

Comment: Here's a working example using an array. http://www.fbrell.com/saved/b4620e6c5533a1f4650b5b818ca01bea

Comment: I followed your example and created a web page with FB.ui send dialog, but only the first recipient appears. I also tried using `to:[]` with no recipients listed, but that just makes the To: field empty with no way to choose recipients. Perhaps my app isn't properly set up?

Comment: i asked about this in the facebook developer forum, and nobody has bothered to confirm or deny it, but i'm guessing that the example above only workd becaue fbrell is running an older version of API that allows multiple UID.

Comment: It's likely fbrell.com is whitelisted for all API features. It loads the same JS api version as every other site.

Answer (score 0):

1. They are definitely using the [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), looking at the dialog that comes up, the header says **Send a Message**, which comes only for the send dialog.
2. Multi friends can be pre selected provided you get the friendlist somehow, using either their user-ids(numeric) or usernames(alphanumeric). But you don't pass array, you pass a csv, like this:

   ```
   FB.ui({
       method: 'send',
       to: '123123123,234234234',
       name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
       link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes, it works in the test console, but doesn't work in my app. In the meantime I've got an invite to Pinterest, and the invite screen looks different, you can only invite users individually. The Facebook documentation doesn't mention anything about multiple recipients, so I think this feature has been removed recently.

Comment: ... or the screenshot in the question is not how it appeared initially, i.e. might have appeared with only 1 recipient and the user added the rest

Comment: i'm trying to write comments with named urls, but its not working!! anyway, yeah in the console it appears correctly, i agree about the screenshot bit. i'm trying to test a few more things, btw can you tell me if your user is connected to your app?

Comment: i have done all the tests i could, it definitely seems to be a bug, as mentioned by @Alesandro Ortiz in his answer. So until you are as successful as pinterest, you will have to do that another way.